# Better Captcha on Programmers blog

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-attributes

I think that the Captchas on the [Programmers Blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com) are a bit too difficult to do. This may be a good thing if you are trying to prevent comments (sarcasm, did not think I needed to say it but question was edited to mean the opposite), cannot understand the words on many of them. Plus, the form is not re-entrant (meaning if you get the captcha wrong you lose what you wrote unless you go back in browser - and in the future someone does not add the header to not cache or whatever browsers want to not keep the previous page(s).

Can we fix this? A good captcha would be some of the new ones I have seen that ask you a question and you need to choose one of four, or even a home grown one with varying font style and sizes, plus random noise (lines, dots ...)

Comment: I changed the reCaptcha theme from "red" to "clear". That might help. There aren't, at present, any other options for comment spam prevention.

Comment: thank you it looks a bit clearer. can you delete my last comment  : "test comment please delete. want to see if i can get the captcha right"

Comment: btw the CAPTCHA should go away if you log in, and you can log in with the same credentials you use for Programmers. It's not a perfect solution for unparseable CAPTCHAs, but it's a good enough workaround.

Comment: alas @yannis-rizos you see the world with your filters. for us lesser mortals a mere login dont make the catch go away.  it stays till we earn our stripes (more rep?)

Comment: Hm, you're right, I just logged in and the CAPTCHA is there. Perhaps it only goes away after you posted a couple of comments, and reappears periodically. I don't think reputation (or mod status) have anything to do with it.

Comment: oh that is a pity. i was hoping it goes away with higher rep/ or more uses. like the ads